# Google PubSub Reliability

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

Is Google PubSub suitable for low-volume (10 msg/sec) but mission-critical messaging, where timely delivery of each message is guaranteed within any fixed period of time?

Or, is it rather suited for high-throughput, where individual messages might be occasionally lost or delayed indefinitely?

Edit: To rephrase this question a bit: Is it true, that any particular message in PubSub, regardless of volume of messages produced, can be indefinitely delayed?

Answer (score 6):

Google Cloud Pub/Sub guarantees delivery of all messages, whether low throughput or high throughput, so there should be no concern about messages being lost.

Latency for message delivery from publisher to subscriber depends on many different factors. In particular, the rate at which the subscriber is able to process messages and request more messages is vitally important. For pull subscribers, this means always having several outstanding pull requests to the server. For push subscribers, they should be returning a successful HTTP response code as quickly as possible. You can read more about the [difference between push and pull subscribers](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#push_pull).

Google Cloud Pub/Sub tries to minimize latency as much as possible, though there are no guarantees made. Empirically, Cloud Pub/Sub consistently delivers messages in no more than a couple of seconds at the 99th percentile. Note that if your publishers or subscribers are not running on Google Cloud Platform, then network latency between your servers and Google servers could also be a factor.

Comment: Thanks! But first you say "guarantees delivery of all messages", then you say "there are no guarantees made". To me, it means an individual message might arrive with any delay whatsoever.

Comment: There are no guarantees about latency, but Cloud Pub/Sub does guarantee it won't lose messages. In other words, latency caused by the service certainly isn't ever going to exceed 7 days, the expiration time of messages. Eventually, Cloud Pub/Sub may provide latency guarantees. However, end-to-end guarantees are difficult to quantify because they are very much based on client behavior.

Comment: No guarantees about latency equally means messages can be lost from the business point of view. Anyway, thanks. Re the quantification, would be helpful if Google (or anyone else) could share some delay histograms of most common scenarios, such as high/low-volume traffic, traffic with spikes, etc. Couple of sec for 99th is rather vague.

Comment: As it is a common pitfall I think it's worth mentioning that Pub/Sub offers "At least once delivery" this means that the subscriber needs to handle duplicates/guarantee idempotency.

Comment: Exactly once delivery is currently in public preview: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery